# xd-admin node service pid error

Tags: linux, spring, pid, spring-xd

**We are trying to know the status of spring-xd-admin service.**

**Executed command :**

**Gives following error:**

```
[root@hostname run]# service spring-xd-admin status
xd-admin dead but pid file exists
```

**Then we tried kill the  process associated to spring-xd-admin**

**in /var/run/xd-admin.pid**

**Executed :**

```
[root@hostname run]# kill 25376
-bash: kill: (25376) - No such process
```

**Then we tried removing the xd-admin.pid file
also Didn't work**

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Could you elaborate on the last part - how did you remove the `xd-admin.pid` file and did you get any errors? How do you conclude that it didn't work?

Comment: We  are facing  same error. please give us direction.so that we can intitate our container service